# How do I tell if a user is using Brave as their browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been messing around with the *Brave* browser (https://www.brave.com/), an I cannot figure out how to determine how if a user is using *Brave*. I used a simple document to output the user agent:

```html
<script>document.write(navigator.userAgent);</script>
```

and I get:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36

which doesn't really help me in my situation. Does anyone know how to determine anyone using *Brave* in PHP or JavaScript? Thanks!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on a mac. `navigator.userAgent` in the console of freshly downloaded Brave for mac from https://www.brave.com/ gives me:
`"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) brave/0.9.0 Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Brave/0.37.3 Safari/537.36"` (see the `brave/0.9.0` part identifying that the browser is brave)

Comment: I too am unable to reproduce this getting essentially the same UA string back.

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with the Windows version of Brave? `(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)`

Comment: https://udger.com/resources/ua-list - no user agent string given for brave, weird.

Comment: just pretend it's chrome; why would you need to know it's brave anyway? afaik, brave supports the same techs that chrome does. use feature detection if needed, not browser sniffing.

Comment: one use case for why you would want to know if its brave was if you had a page that autodetects which browser is visiting in order to display information regarding specific browser extensions for that browser. Although brave is built on chrome technology, brave only has a handful of officially sanctioned extensions at present, and installing non sanctioned extensions is a bit of a palaver at present.

Comment: @dandavis - bad idea.  How do you feature detect deeplink urlschemes capability?  Browsers like DuckDuckGo don't fully support them - thus you need to detect the browser type to know to alert the user the browser lacks capabilities or present another option for the feature

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kohjah Breese's solution isn't working to detect Brave on Android (e.g. Chrome is detected as Brave). But as he said "If you search DuckDuckGo for [what's my user agent] they will return Brave." Then you can use the API of Duckduckgo to know if they browser is Brave :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=useragent&format=json', true)

request.onload = function () {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  var isBrave = data['Answer'].includes('Brave');
  if(isBrave){
    console.log( isBrave );
  }
}

request.send()
```

Comment: Thank You! I refactored your response into a promise & made a public gist. https://gist.github.com/ZachMoreno/5c2f7f189e4bc3d3ba907b3d20bdeb84

Comment: @ZachariahMoreno Np :)

Comment: doesn't work on my request using brave

Answer (score 31):

As of April 2020, you can use [this detection method](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/brave-user-agent-detection.html) to get a boolean answer to whether the user is using Brave or not:

```
(navigator.brave && await navigator.brave.isBrave() || false)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer even confirmed by one of the brave devs https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/10165#issuecomment-641128278

Comment: This results in "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in Chrome, which is less than ideal.

Comment: Is there some alternative without the `await` keyword in it? Why should I even call that thing (without checking it's callable) when no other browser even defines `navigator.brave`. I guess that part of the test is sufficient, the rest is just problematic. My version: `!!navigator.brave`

Comment: This is working perfectly on desktop browsers. However, it does not seem to be working on mobile. Does anyone have a snippet that works on all devices?

Comment: an answer relying on async is far from ideal,
maybe it's the only reliable way, but then, Brave dev should really provide something better

Answer (score 17):

There is a way to check if the user is using brave without any api calls.
I created the below function that returns false or True if its Brave

```js
function isBrave() {
  if (window.navigator.brave != undefined) {
    if (window.navigator.brave.isBrave.name == "isBrave") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = isBrave();
```

```html
Is this Brave? <span id="ans"></span>
```

Comment: This is a good answer answer, it is more faster. But this will not work in android, and some other devices that uses mobile apps.

Answer (score 15):

The "Brave" in the user agent was removed in the 0.9 version.

From the [changelog](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> Removed Brave from the User Agent HTTP header to reduce
>   fingerprinting.

Comment: Still a few dozen ways to detect it. Brave behaves differently on many fronts. Any browser can be detected via feature detection.

Comment: @Bangkokian brave specifically tries to avoid being detectable - they consider it an invasion of privacy for a website to be able to find out which browser you're using.

Comment: @abhibeckert That's fine. I don't really care what they "try" to do or what they "consider" to be an invasion of privacy. Brave is detectable and blockable.

Comment: @Bangkokian - could you please tell me at least one way to detect it? Been trying for days now... no solution whatsoever :(

Comment: @mariobgr one method, make a call to a resource that brave blocks, if the request fails nearly-instantly then the user is on Brave. This method could have false positives so be careful, but it is effective as a quick and dirty approach

Comment: I tried that, but with active AdBlock the false positives are more than acceptable :(

Comment: Checking by requesting a blocked resource would have far too many false positives to be useful. Any Chrome extension using the same or similar block lists would look like Brave, and that may be a lot of Chrome users depending on your audience.

Answer (score 8):

Brave appears has some different objects in the window object. I'm not sure how contiguous these are across Brave versions, but I noted two in the window.navigator object that are blanked out: plugins and mimeTypes. Since Brave is meant to be a privacy browser I think it's a good chance these will remain blanked. So my check is to check the length of those.

**Please note that you also need to check for the browser being desktop first; it doesn't seem you can detect the Brave Mobile browser; and the below code will pick up many mobile browsers**

```
var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isChrome = /chrome|crios/.test(agent) && ! /edge|opr\//.test(agent);
var isBrave = isChrome && window.navigator.plugins.length === 0 && window.navigator.mimeTypes.length === 0;
if(isBrave)
    console.log( isBrave );
```

If you search DuckDuckGo for [what's my user agent] they will return Brave. If you open the attached JS files you will find an elaborate browser detection that can detect Brave.

Comment: I just tried this and `isChrome` is `true` and `isBrave` is `false` in the latest Brave.

Answer (score 6):

Brave has the same user agent as Chrome. But Chrome itself add a lot (1768 as for now) of chrome-specific properties to *window* object. One of them is *window.google*. So detecting Brave is pretty simple (as for now):

```
const ua = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
const isChrome = /chrome|crios/.test(ua) && ! /edge|opr\//.test(ua)
const isBrave = isChrome && ! window.google;
```

So brave, lol.

Comment: As for Jul 2019, this doesn't work. Both Chrome and Brave return "isBrave: true". :(

Answer (score 3):

Brave doesn’t have its own User-Agent, as pointed out in other answers. However, you can quite easily fingerprint it to differentiate it from Google Chrome. The current release, version 0.23.19, has at least 40 unique characteristics that can tell it apart from other browsers. I go into more detail on that in [this article](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/brave-user-agent-detection.html). However, this is a riddiculous sulution. Please just [ask Brave to restore their own User-Agent](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues) string.

Comment: i have a feeling Brave is cloaking itself because it's trying to avoid it's built in ad removal features being picked up by all the sites who do things like, "We notice you're using an adblocker" stuff and basically force a bunch of bloat down your throat or not see the page. I'd say, instead of asking Brave to restore, don't the us devs make sites like that. Or sites with auto-start vids without an opt out option

Answer (score 2):

**2020. Updated solution:**

Chrome now adds a new key to the window object: *googletag*, as opposed to the old one: *google*

This is the working code now:

```
const ua = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
const isChrome = /chrome|crios/.test(ua) && ! /edge|opr\//.test(ua)
const isBrave = isChrome && ! window.googletag;
```

Comment: I just tested this an this no longer works. I got `isChrome`: true and `isBrave`: false...

Comment: Same here, just tested and it doesn't work. isBrave ends up as 'true' on Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Brave has a class `Brave`, which is created and added to navigator as `navigator.brave` upon page load. It has one method which returns a promise: `Brave.prototype.isBrave()`
Using these three you can create a check for brave browser (something like this):

```
var isBrave = false;
if(window.Brave&&navigator.brave&&navigator.brave.isBrave){
    isBrave = 'probable';//or some other value, as you wish
    navigator.brave.isBrave().then(function(r){
        if(r)isBrave = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: im a bit confused as to why all the extra code is necessary, surely testing for
 `navigator.brave  !== undefined` 
would be enough, or am i missing something

Comment: it would, but i'm just thinking about people changing things. someone might want you to think that they ARE brave, when they're NOT. or the other way round. if you're not worried about that, and most people aren't, then that would do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am used this bit of code as when I looked in the window object for window.google or window.googletag or window.Brave they were no longer there. So I looked in the window object and they no longer existed.

const keys = Object.keys(window);

console.log(keys);

So the three window objects that have been written about to detect Brave no longer work.

I also tried the duckduckgo.com method but that doesn't mention brave at all I literally took the code from this page >

[https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=useragent&format=json](https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=useragent&format=json&atb=v1-1)

and tried both AJAX and just pasting it in the browser address bar and it doesn't return Brave it returns (and I am in Brave now) this >

> {"Abstract":"","AbstractSource":"Wikipedia","AbstractText":"","AbstractURL":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UserAgent","Answer":"Your user agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36","AnswerType":"useragent","Definition":"","DefinitionSource":"","DefinitionURL":"","Entity":"","Heading":"UserAgent","Image":"","ImageHeight":0,"ImageIsLogo":0,"ImageWidth":0,"Infobox":"","Redirect":"","RelatedTopics":[],"Results":[],"Type":"E","meta":{"attribution":null,"blockgroup":null,"created_date":null,"description":"Wikipedia","designer":null,"dev_date":null,"dev_milestone":"live","developer":[{"name":"DDG Team","type":"ddg","url":"http://www.duckduckhack.com"}],"example_query":"nikola tesla","id":"wikipedia_fathead","is_stackexchange":null,"js_callback_name":"wikipedia","live_date":null,"maintainer":{"github":"duckduckgo"},"name":"Wikipedia","perl_module":"DDG::Fathead::Wikipedia","producer":null,"production_state":"online","repo":"fathead","signal_from":"wikipedia_fathead","src_domain":"en.wikipedia.org","src_id":1,"src_name":"Wikipedia","src_options":{"directory":"","is_fanon":0,"is_mediawiki":1,"is_wikipedia":1,"language":"en","min_abstract_length":"20","skip_abstract":0,"skip_abstract_paren":0,"skip_end":"0","skip_icon":0,"skip_image_name":0,"skip_qr":"","source_skip":"","src_info":""},"src_url":null,"status":"live","tab":"About","topic":["productivity"],"unsafe":0}}

So that didn't work and other sites that do Browser sniffing don't show Brave either just Chrome or Netscape e.g paste that user-agent:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36

into the box on this site >>

https://webbrowsertools.com/useragent/?method=normal&verbose=false

and there are 3 methods of detection, the navigator object, and two different JavaScript files platform.js and ua-parser.js. None of them get Brave.

Nor does this page > https://www.iplocation.net/ (which uses Request headers to get the user-agent)
or > https://whichbrowser.net/ (which supposedly uses a complex method to detect the real browser you are using but just shows Chrome)

I tried many other sites like those that either the Request headers or the Navigator object and none worked.

Also when I test for plugins OR mimetypes I get a list of plugins back and I also get a length of 2 for MimeTypes and their details if I want them so that method doesn't work anymore either.

Therefore I used this function from > http://blog.strictly-software.com/2022/01/testing-for-brave-browser.html

I know that with extensions and injected code we could easily add properties to the window or navigator object, if we couldn't then user-agent switchers wouldn't exist.

This function seems to try to future proof by
a) hoping one day Brave will have it's own User-Agent like it used to, not to long back I remember seeing Brave in the user-agent string.
b) Also by hoping like one answer said that a Brave property would be returned to the window object e.g window.Brave as it is no longer there.

It checks for a Mozilla specific property on the Window object first to rule that out before doing some positive tests for Brave with various fallbacks.

As most modern browsers apart from FireFox are based on Chromium now, Chrome, Edge, Brave, Opera it rules out those by a user-agent regex test as a last resort. However, the first two branches should detect whether it is Brave or not.

For some reason even though perfectly indented in my page when I post inside the code section it kept missing off the top and bottom lines, so that is why the function and ending } are not indented properly

```
function IsBrave(ua){

var isBrave = false;

// user-agent may or may not be passed in if not get current navigator agent
ua = (ua === null || ua === undefined) ? ua = window.navigator.userAgent : ua;

ua = ua.toLowerCase();

// make sure not it's not Mozilla by looking for a Moz specific property on the window object
if("mozInnerScreenX" in window){        
    return isBrave;
}else{
    // everything in JavaScript is over writable we could do this to pass the next test 
    // but then where would we stop as every object even window/navigator can be overwritten or changed...?
    // window.chrome="mozilla";
    // window.webkitStorageInfo = "mozilla";

    // make sure its chrome and webkit
    if("chrome" in window && "webkitStorageInfo" in window){
        // it looks like Chrome and has webkit
        if("brave" in navigator && "isBrave" in navigator.brave){
            isBrave = true;
        // test for Brave another way the way the framwwork Prototype checks for it
        }else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(navigator.brave) == '[object Brave]'){
            isBrave = true;         
        // have they put brave back in window object like they used to
        }else if("Brave" in window){
            isBrave = true;         
        // hope one day they put brave into the user-agent
        }else if(ua.indexOf("brave") > -1){
            isBrave = true;
        // make sure there is no mention of Opera or Edge in UA
        }else if(/chrome|crios/.test(ua) && /edge?|opera|opr\//.test(ua) && !navigator.brave){
            isBrave = false;            
        }
    }

    return isBrave;

}
```

Of course, it is not perfect but it is working for me, the site also has a one-liner if you don't want all the fallbacks and future-proofing.

```
var w=window,n=w.navigator; // shorten key objects
let isBrave = !("mozInnerScreenX" in w) && ("chrome" in w && "webkitStorageInfo" in w && "brave" in n && "isBrave" in n.brave) ? true : false;
```

I updated it so that the 2nd test for Brave was the Prototype test as the other way I was doing was just a repeat of the 1st in a different manner. Also I was testing the fall through if the objects didn't exist and changing navigator.brave.IsBrave() to IsBraver() was causing an error but doing it the "isBraver" in navigator.brave way I could fall through to the 2nd branch without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Following some comments, it is enough to check if `window.brave` is defined. See [this comment](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/10165#issuecomment-644949774).