# Detecting if user uses Brave in JS

Tags: javascript, brave

Is there *any* way to detect if the user is using Brave browser in Javascript?

I've checked the useragent but it's identical to Chrome's. Is there any specific Brave feature I could detect?

Answer (score 1):

Fomr this post : [How do I tell if a user is using Brave as their browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523448/how-do-i-tell-if-a-user-is-using-brave-as-their-browser/56459333#56459333) : 
"If you search DuckDuckGo for [what's my user agent] they will return Brave." Then you can use the API of Duckduckgo to know if they browser is Brave :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=useragent&format=json', true)

request.onload = function () {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  var isBrave = data['Answer'].includes('Brave');
  if(isBrave){
    console.log( isBrave );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Version 0.9.0 Removed Brave from the user agent.

https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#090

And from this issue https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues/3693 there's privacy concerns that point that it won't have a unique user agent.

Comment: Hmm... [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) is able to show an "Add DuckDuckGo to Brave" button...

Comment: Sorry for commenting one month later but - that's probably because Brave partnered with DuckDuckGo