# How to detect brave using navigator

Tags: user-agent, navigator, brave-browser

I am trying to detect brave using navigator. I referred to this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60954062/14443512

I tried this condition,
`(navigator.brave && await navigator.brave.isBrave() || false)`

But I get error, `Property 'brave' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.`

Am I missing any configuration here?

My code block,

```
export const errorMessage = (networkError: netError): string | undefined => {
    const {statusCode, message} = networkError;
    if (statusCode === undefined) {
        return message;
    }
    if (statusCode < 400) {
        return undefined;
    }
    switch (statusCode) {
        case 401:
            return 'authn error';
        case 403:
            if(navigator.brave && await navigator.brave.isBrave() || false)
            return 'browser not supported';

else 
return 'authz error';
        case 500:
            if (message.includes("invalid value")) {
                return invalidString;
            }
            break;
    }
    if (statusCode < 500) {
        return 'error';
    }
    return 'serverError';
};
```

Comment: I tested your code via `DevTools` in `Brave`, `Chromium` and `Firefox` - it works (`true`, `false`, `false`).

Comment: Yeah, in the IDE, I got this error. I am using react with typescript.

Comment: show more your code

Comment: Updated question with code block

Comment: did you define type 'Navigator' in ts ? if you did show how

Comment: oh I have not added any config for Navigation.

Comment: yes I think this issue about that

Comment: I am not able to find the right configuration for it. Could you tell me what to add in tsconfig.json?

Comment: Also, for chrome and firefox it didn't give me error, 
if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") === -1) && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") === -1))

Answer (score 0):

I think that the declaration should be something like this:

```
export {}; // there must be at least one export in this file

declare global {
  interface Navigator {
    brave: {
      isBrave(): boolean;
    };
  }
  interface Global {
    document: Document;
    window: Window;
    navigator: Navigator,
  } 
}
```